# Repeat Javascript Function For Each Value

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, repeat

i hava two question : 
1 - for function with input value how i can set interval i test this but now working

```
<script>
function bn(x)
{
alert (x);
}
setInterval("bn(x)",3000);
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="bn(1);">bn 1</a><br>
```

with `setInterval("bn()",3000);` work but show 'undefine' insteadof '1'

an 2- how Set repeat for two value mean when repeat this function i try for new value and function repeat for two value

```
<script>
function bn(x)
{
alert (x);
}
setInterval("bn(x)",3000);
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="bn(1);">bn 1</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="bn(2);">bn 2</a>
```

Comment: You're passing an undefined `x` into the function repeatedly.

Comment: What do you mean to do by `setInterval("bn(x)",3000);`?

Comment: `setInterval(function() { bn(x); });` is better than putting the function call in a string. It basically uses eval under the hood and makes it hard to access variables in the global scope.

Comment: i wnat repeat evry 3 second and show 1 insteadof undefine

Comment: @behzadn You aren't making much sense; you just want it to show the alert of '1' every three seconds?

Comment: yes show input valueevry 3 second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you want; see below:

For your first question, what you are currently doing will obviously not work(as you've likely figured out).  To fix that, you must use an anonymous function; example below:

```
<script>
var x = 1;

function bn(x)
{
    alert (x);
}
setInterval(function() {
    bn(x);
},3000);

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="x = 1;">bn 1</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="x = 2;">bn 2</a>
```

As to your second question, see the last two lines above; as the function is already running all you need to control is the value of `x`, and make sure you set its scope as general, as opposed to specific to the function in which it is used.

The onclick events set the value of `x`.  I've made sure the code works; if the value is set to `2`, then the alert will display `2`, etc.

Comment: with this code i have to use on function for evry input value?

Comment: @behzadn I've just modified my answer, see if it fits your needs, though I'm still unsure as to what you want.

You do not need to run the function for every anchor you have, just modify the value of x.  If you want to modify how that value is set.. it gets more complicated.

Comment: I guess this code would work you could actually remove the x parameter on the bn function and just call it as bn() instead since the x variable is already a global variable

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo True; I hadn't realized that while typing the answer, given I was doing it in two sections while still trying to understand what the OP meant by the second half.  I would change my answer now, but I'm unsure how they would react to that change.

Comment: i want how use this code in one time . example when 1 repeat and click 2 . 1 and 2 work mean 1.5second 1 and 1.5 second 2

Comment: `1 and 2 work 'etc'`?  I am afraid I am still having difficulty understanding what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function bn(x) {
  alert(x);
}
setInterval(function() { bn(1) }, 3000)
</script>
```

will call `bn` every 3 seconds and pass it the value `1`

The reason you were getting undefined before is because you were trying to pass `x` which (in the code you posted) has never been declared.

The parameters you pass to a function don't have to have the same name as the function arguments..

```
<script>
var some_var = 1;
function bn(x) {
   alert(x);
}
setInterval(function() { bn(some_var) }, 3000);
</script>
```

Will do the same thing as the previous example but you'll be able to change some_var elsewhere in your script and have that updated value passed into bn.